# How to use ASP.NET 4.8 ConfigBuilders with system.serviceModel section of web.config

Tags: asp.net, service-model, asp-net-config-builders

I have an ASP.NET 4.8 app that I am trying to integrate configuration builders into. I have installed the NuGet package `Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment` and added the required sections to `Web.config` (heavily truncated here).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>

  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
      <add name="EnvironmentExpand" mode="Expand" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.EnvironmentConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment" />
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>

  <system.serviceModel configBuilders="EnvironmentExpand">
....
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I run the application I get an HTTP 500 response from every action, with the message `Unrecognized attribute 'configBuilders'`. Intellisense in Visual Studio also highlights `configBuilders` and says `The configBuilders attribute is not allowed`.

If I remove the `configBuilders` attribute from `system.serviceModel` the application runs correctly although of course none of the placeholders in that section are expanded.

If I remove the `configBuilders` attribute from `system.serviceModel` and add it to another section, for instance `connectionStrings`, the application runs and the placeholders in the `connectionStrings` section are replaced.

Clearly there's something different about the `system.serviceModel` section but I don't understand what or how I can work around it so that I can replace placeholders in there.

Comment: I have the exact problem with the `<rewrite>` section. "Unrecognized attribute 'configBuilders'" is all I get on pretty much any section other than <connectionStrings> or <appSettings> which kinda makes the whole thing useless for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your machine.config, you'll see that `system.serviceModel` is a `sectionGroup` and not a `section`. ConfigurationBuilders only apply at the section level. WCF and ASP.Net for better or worse have their large configuration divided into multiple sections.